# Exclude directory from laravel 4 routing

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have laravel4 installed at my webserver in the sub directory laravel4 of my web root. in this web root directory there is another directory called modx which serves a MODX cms. before I had laravel4 installed i could open www.mydomain/modx to get the frontend of the cms. Now it is controled by laravel and I get an error. Web server is an apache2.

Maybe an illustration is better:

```
webroot /var/www/
   │
   ├--laravel4/      <-serve/process via laravel
   ├--modx/          <-do not process via laravel
```

So what do I need to configure the only the laravel4 sub-directory is affected by laravel? is it the .htaccess file?

Answer (score 1):

The best practice and for security sake, you should put laravel folder somewhere else other than web root.

And add a symlink from laravel folder to your web root. For example, execute following in Terminal

ln -s  /path/to/your/laravel-master/public  /path/to/your/web_root/laravel